# Laravel Livewire Pagination Not Displaying Search Results After Index Page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I've seen other posts about this same question, but none of them mirrored my setup, which makes it difficult for me to implement.

I am using Laravel 8.0 and Livewire 1.3

I currently have an 'items' list of 186 items with pagination at 25 per page--this works great. I also have live search and if on the index page, it works great, but if you are on any page after index, for example `http://workorders.test/items?page=2` and decide to do a search, it will show the correct number of results, but not display the results to the page(see attached screenshot).

[image]

**index.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Items;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Item;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Index extends Component
{
    use withPagination;
    public $item;
    public $item_name;
    public $item_description;
    public $perPage = 25;
    public $sortAsc = true;
    public $search = '';
    public $sortField = 'item_name';

    ...

    public function render()
    {
        $types = collect([
            ['name' => 'Equipment'],
            ['name' => 'Supply'],
        ]);

        $plucked = $types->pluck('name')->all();

        $items = Item::search($this->search)
            ->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortAsc ? 'asc' : 'desc')
            ->paginate($this->perPage);
        return view('livewire.admin.items.index', compact('items', 'plucked'));
    }
}
```

**item.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Item extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = [
        'item_name', 'item_description'
    ];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }

    public static function search($query)
    {
        return empty($query) ? static::query()
            : static::where('item_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%');
    }

}
```

**index.blade**
*(Stripped to show only important pieces)*

```
<div class="flex-1 min-w-0 rounded-md shadow-sm">
   <input wire:model="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Item Name">
</div>
...
@foreach($items as $item)
   ... 
@endforeach
...
{{ $items->links() }}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're missing something. When you use a filter like that, you need to tell livewire to reset the page.

In your case, the filter is stored in the `$search` variable so just add this method to your Livewire Component:

```php
public function updatingSearch()
{
    $this->resetPage();
}
```